# Using Mac App preconfigured menu items in xcode 7

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, menu, items

I'm coding some simple Mac apps to learn more about various cocoa programming topics, and while adding/removing and coding new menu items seems pretty straight forward, I'm having trouble getting my head around the large selection of preconfigured menu items and how to use them properly. (Just for a learning experience).

For example, a Mac app based on the OS X, Cocoa application template in Xcode 7.x will have a pretty complete menu already in place. But how do you use it? The App->About menu item will display the about box and Quit will quit the app, but how do you use the others?

I have and idea surfacing that it has something to do with the responder chain and the current context, but I'm not sure.

I tried experimenting with a text field and found that I could change the font color of selected text and use undeline if the "Allows Rich text" option is selected in attribute inspector. The color picker can be activated from the app's menu and sure enough, it changes the text color. But where is the code and how does it know I have selected some text? Several other menu items are available as well, but others are disabled. For example, I can't select bold or italics.

Sorry if it's a long question, but I haven't been able to find any clear explanations of how these preconfigured menu items work.

If it has any influence, I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say the question is rather broad and it will take more than a SO answer for complete treatments. But I will try to give some hints (I'm no expert on storyboards but I think it is the same).

All menu entries work the same. When you click it an action is triggered (a method with a target). You can see that in the connections inspector pane in IB.

The action can be directed to a specific target like a viewController or to a generic target such as First Responder (== nil). With the latter approach the message call will follow the responder chain up through the app until it finds someone that responds (or none).

As you have noted some menu choices already work, e.g. Quit. That is because they are pre-wired with an action (Exit sends `terminate:` to First Responder). Then this method is implemented somewhere in the App scaffolding provided by the project, for the example `terminate:` is implemented by the NSApplication singleton that is at the end of the responder chain.

To make other menu choices work the way you want find out their predefined action, e.g Copy sends `copy:` to First Responder. Then implement that action method in an object in the responder chain. For testing put them in the App delegate which is toward the end of the chain.

If you need specific behaviour for diferent windows, like for example Print, put a `print:` method in each window controller. The first one in the responder chain will catch the command and you will get different behaviour depending on which window is at the top.

Comment: Thanks, that kinda makes sense :-)